# Desktop enviroments for Ubuntu

Tags: desktop-environments

Does anyone know if Canonical will ever release Ubuntu with more then one (Unity, which is currently official) desktop environment like Linux Mint does (Cinnamon,MATE,Xfce)?

Comment: That's what Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Kubuntu, Ubuntu GNOME are for... You need to consider that Canonical has limited manpower, the "flavors" are maintained by the community (sponsored by Canonical, yes) and that's awesome. (But who knows what's in the future ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question would be best answered by someone from Canonical but till then ...

Canonical's focus seems to be on "convergence": having as close to the *same* experience across form factors. This is a technically challenging task.

You can read more here:

- [Canonical says smartphone focus makes Ubuntu 13.04 more efficient](http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2263810/canonical-says-smartphone-focus-makes-ubuntu-1304-more-efficient)
- [Can a single OS work for all the devices in your life?](http://www.techradar.com/news/phone-and-communications/mobile-phones/canonical-s-long-road-to-the-ubuntu-phone-1206455)

This is not to say that it isn't possible to offer several official flavors across devices but I wouldn't bet on it.